# What to do wine32 installation breaks my kali guest and prevent login?

Tags: linux, boot, vmware, wine

I am running kali(4.3.0-amd64) guest in vmware.I need veil-evasion whose prerequities is wine32(if u don't know then just say it is an emulator to run window app).

The prorblem i'm facing is after installation of wine32 when i restart my kali guest it stucks at login.when password is correct the screen turns black like it is about to start but the revert back to login screen.

For wrong it simply shows incorrect password.

So what do i do ?

Answer (score -1):

corupted package :libgl1-mesa-dri

prevent from installing using: apt-mark hold libgl1-mesa-dri

After that install wine32 normally it will not break this time :-)